# What is the replacement pattern in rewrite ouput for current user id?

Tags: views, 8

I have a custom content entity listed with Views.
I want to conditionally display some information depending on the fact that the row is related to the current user.
I tried {{ user:uid }} with no success.
Any idea?

With help from @4k4, I could use 'Custom text' to add on each row of my Views output two 'buttons' (Edit, Delete) depending on the current user:

```
{% if user_id_1=="[current-user:uid]"  %}
<a href="/sel/service/{{ id }}/edit"><img src="/sites/default/files/images/document-edit.gif" alt="" title="Modifier" width="11" height="13"></a>
<a href="/sel/service/{{ id }}/delete"><img src="/sites/default/files/images/trash.gif" alt="" title="Supprimer" width="11" height="13"></a>
{% endif %}
```

[image]
As you can see, there is also a button in the header (Add).
I'd like to have this button displayed only if the user is not anonymous.
I tried (in either Text area or Unfiltered text):

```
{% if "0"=="[current-user:uid]"  %}
<a href="/sel/service/add" class="form-submit hiddenforuser[current-user:uid]">Ajouter</a>
{% endif %}
```

but it doesn't work:
[image]
Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The twig variables in `{{ }}` are replacement patterns for fields. Globally available tokens are accessed by their usual square brackets syntax:

```
[current-user:uid]
```

## Custom text field

This token works in a global text area, but not a custom text field, because this plugin *Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\Custom* doesn't have global token replacement. You need to extend it and override renderAltered():

*/src/Plugin/views/field/CustomToken.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\Custom;

/**
 * A handler to provide a field extending custom by global token replacement.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("custom")
 */
class CustomToken extends Custom {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
protected function renderAltered($alter, $tokens) {
    return $this->viewsTokenReplace($this->globalTokenReplace($alter['text']), $tokens);
  }
}
```

and tell the plugin manager about the new class:

*mymodule.module:*

```
function mymodule_views_plugins_field_alter(array &$plugins) {
  $plugins['custom']['class'] = 'Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\field\CustomToken';
}
```

This applies the function `globalTokenReplace()` before the twig patterns are replaced.

Then you can use

```
{% if anotherfield_id == '[current-user:uid]' %} YES {% else %} NO {% endif %}
```

You have to enclose the token in single quotes so that you get a valid twig syntax after the global tokens are replaced.

## Global text area

A global text area in header/footer is exactly the opposite, it supports global tokens but not Twig.

You could do the same as before and add Twig support in a custom plugin. But there is an easier solution. Install the module [Twig input filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig) and go to "Text formats and editors" in Configuration and enable the Twig filter for the text format you use in the text area.

Comment: I added a global custom text field in my view.  
When I put  [current-user:uid] in the text of this field, I get "[current-user:uid]" and not the value (should be 1). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've just tested it in a global text area, it works there. Do you have the Token module installed?

Comment: I just installed Token module. I have now a nice (and quite impressive) list of tokens. But my global text area with [current-user:uid] in it still displays "[current-user:uid]". Is there anything else to do before using these tokens in Views?

Comment: It works when I use it in a global text area in the header of my View. Still doesn't when used in a global custom text field in each row. And I need that as I want to display/hide depending on something like `{% if anotherfield_id == [current-user:uid] %}
YES
{% else %}
NO
{% endif %}`

Comment: The custom field plugin has indeed no global token replacement, so you would need to extend it, see the edited answer.

Comment: Where should I put renderAltered() to be effective for all my site?  In any of my custom modules? Or is there a 'best practice' location?

Comment: Hello! I added a second question to my first one: same topic but at Views header level... Any suggestion?

Comment: In the header you have global tokens but no twig, see the edit.

Comment: OK. Got it! Finally, I used another solution: I put `<div class="visibleforuser[current-user:account-name]"><a href="/sel/service/add" class="form-submit">Ajouter</a></div>` in the global text area and added this to a CSS file:
`div[class^="visibleforuser"] {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
div[class$="visibleforuser"] {
    display: none;
}`