# Get the user's current language code

Tags: views, 8, tokens

How can I get the user's current language code in a view as a raw value, for example *en* or *fr-ca*?

This isn't for filtering content. I need the raw value of the users' current language to pass into a URL for a third-party tool. I added a custom text field. Then placed in some Twig code. The code is just failing to the fallback `else` value.

Based on other forum posts, I tried this code.

```
{% if language.getId() == 'en' %}
  en
{% elseif language.getId() == 'es-us' %}
  es-us
{% elseif language.getId() == 'en-us' %}
  en-us
{% else %}
  failed
{% endif %}
```

I get *failed*.

```
{% if language == 'en' %} 
  en
{% elseif language == 'es-us' %}
  es-us
{% elseif language == 'en-us' %}
  en-us
{% else %}
  failed
{% endif %}
```

I still get *failed*.

```
{% if language.id() == 'en' %}
  en
{% elseif language.id() == 'es-us' %}
  es-us
{% elseif language.id() == 'en-us' %}
  en-us
{% else %}
  failed
{% endif %}
```

I still get the same output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current language in template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204289/get-current-language-in-template)

Comment: When you say "User's current language code", do you mean the "current interface language" or a language that the user has selected on their profile?

Comment: @leymannx - unfortunately, no. That is the post I referenced for the above code attempts.

Comment: @CG Monroe - I am attempting to get 'current interface language'

Comment: You need two things, a current language token, see https://www.drupal.org/project/token_language and a views field handler supporting tokens, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/259541/47547

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a custom text field then add the language value as a field. this way you will have the language as a replacement pattern that you can use with any custom link field which would be  something like {{ language }}

You need to checkout the style settings of to use the custom link option.