# get the value of a drupal token inside a twig code

Tags: views, tokens

does anybody knows how to get the value of a drupal token inside a twig code(global text field) block in the views's header?
I can get the value of the token outside the twig code block, but not inside ...

```
[view:page-count]/*token works outside*/

{% set count = [view:page-count]  %} /*does NOT work*/
{% if count == 1 %}
    <p class="text-danger">Atención: en esta región sólo debe haber un artículo  </p>
{% endif %}
```

greetings

Comment: So you have both, token replacement and twig available? Still, you need to consider the Twig syntax after token replacement. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259534/what-is-the-replacement-pattern-in-rewrite-ouput-for-current-user-id

Comment: thanks, I found the solution there: I had to enclose the drupal token in apostrophes, but apart from that I had to  create a special text filter using the contrib module [Twig input filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig) to be able to use full twig code in Global text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclosing the token in apostrophes solved the problem, but apart from that I had to create a special text filter using the contrib module [Twig input filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig) to be able to use full twig code in a views Global text area.

As it seems, Global text area with minimal filtering(also availeble in views), which I was using, does NOT fully support twig.

```
[view:page-count]/*token works outside*/

{% set count = '[view:page-count]'  %} /* this WORKS inside*/
{% if count == 1 %}
    <p class="text-danger">Atención: en esta región sólo debe haber un artículo  </p>
{% endif %}
```